# How to cover up a part os display in Ubuntu-20.10?

Tags: display, laptop, screen, display-resolution

I am very new to Ubuntu, just installed it on an old laptop. That laptop has a screen defect that makes part of the screen unusable. I would like to rechange the size of the display to ignore that part of the screen, or by shrinking the display at all,

[image]

or just by changing the display configuration to ignore that part. Could you guys help me out? I have 0 knowledge of Linux or Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not sure you can resize the display in this manner, but I have a workaround: Use a VM like VirtualBox and you can run another instance of Ubuntu in a window.  It's far from perfect, but might be the only way you can effectively use a display that's broken in this way.

Comment: No idea about Linux, but for Windows I found a little program called Zorro. Might be a starting point for someone coming by in the future.